# Displaying simple search form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.1

I still new with RoR and i am trying to add a simple search form to my app. This is how i proceed.

```
 class BooksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_book, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  def index
     if params[:search]
       @users = User.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
     else
       @users = User.order('created_at DESC')
     end

  end


 def new
  @book= Book.new

  end
  def create
    @book= Book.new(books_params)
    if @book.save
       redirect_to admin_manage_path
    else
     render 'new'
    end

   end

   def list
    @books= Book.all
    end

   def show

   end



  private

   def set_book
   @book = Book.find(params[:id])
   end

  def books_params
     params.require(:book).permit(:title, :author, :price, :resume)

   end
 end
```

my book model

```
 class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

   def self.search(query)
    where('title like ?', "%#{query}%")
   end

   end
```

my list.html.erb where the search form is shown:

```
 <% if current_user.present? %>
Welcome <%= current_user.pseudo %> | <%= link_to 'Déconnexion' , user_logout_path %>
 <% end %>
<br>
<%= form_tag(books_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search books" %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
<br>
```

and my index.html.erb where the search result should be shown:

```
<% @books.each do |b| %>
```

<%= b.title %>

the error diplayed is :

> Couldn't find Book without an ID

and i do not understand what it refer to controller#show method
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in BooksController#show

Answer (score 0):

I found the error's source, i forgot to specify the appropriate route